# Autolayout and Tableview Headers

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I'm trying to recreate the default `viewForHeaderInSection` only with a button in each header, using autolayout. The crux of my layout is:

```
@"|-[titleLabel]-4-[refreshButton(==22)]"
```

This works just fine in both portrait and landscape on my iPhone.

[image]

However, when run on an iPad, the 'titleLabel' is too close to the left margin (because the margins are larger on the iPad). I had hoped that `|-` would use the standard margin to position the label, but it seems not (I guess it just uses a default number of points).

[image]

How can I position this label correctly? Do I need to check for iPad vs iPhone and update a constant? Or can I refer to some constant value that represents the margin size?

Comment: Seems to be this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708085/how-to-determine-margin-of-a-grouped-uitableview-or-better-how-to-set-it

Answer (score 0):

You should add a new constraint which aligns the left edge of the `titleLabel` to the left edge of the `UITableView`. In IB/Storyboard, this is easily done:

1. Select both objects
2. Click the alignment button (the first one in this image: [image])
3. Click align `Left Edges`

Comment: You would think so - except in a UITableViewController: "'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal."