# How to programmatically get the margin of a table in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I used a typical [UITableViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) subclass to set up my page. The grouped [UITableViews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) have different margins on iPad and iPhone. This causes my [tableHeaderView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableHeaderView) to be maligned on at least one of the devices. How do I programmatically get the margin width so I can perfectly align the header to the left of the table? I know that I can measure with Photoshop and hardcode numbers in an `if/else`, but I'd like a more robust solution.

## iPhone

[image]

## iPad

[image]

Comment: Here's at least one idea:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708085/how-to-determine-margin-of-a-grouped-uitableview-or-better-how-to-set-it

Comment: I predict in the future table sections go all the way to the edge.

Comment: @timquinn I predict Apple will converge to Google's design within 2 years because Tim Cook has been publicly reprimanded for being lame :p