# UILabel textRectForBounds has no effect when trying to create margin

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, margins

I'm trying to indent the text in a UILabel to leave some margin around the text showing the background colour. Following the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476646/uilabel-text-margin) I've overriden `textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:` like so:

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds limitedToNumberOfLines:(NSInteger)numberOfLines
{
    CGRect intermediate = CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x+MARGIN,bounds.origin.y+MARGIN,bounds.size.width-2*MARGIN,bounds.size.height-2*MARGIN);
    return [super textRectForBounds:intermediate limitedToNumberOfLines:numberOfLines];
}
```

But no matter what I do, the text ends up tight against the left border of the rectangle. It seems as though the drawing is ignoring the origin part of the returned CGRect (although it seems to be respecting the width part, as if I reduce to width of intermediate to eg `bounds.size.width-200` the rect that textRectForBounds returns is suitably narrow and the text is drawn in a long skinny column).

So: what else I need to do to the `UILabel` to make the drawing respect the `textForRectBounds`-returned-rect's origin.x and origin.y? I'd rather not override `UILabel`'s `drawTextInRect` if I can help it.

**Update**: This was a long time ago and I can't remember exactly why the other question didn't work for me. I believe it was because I was trying to have a `UILabel` with multiple lines, and the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476646/uilabel-text-margin) didn't work in that case.

Comment: Have you tried returning `intermediate` directly?

Comment: yes, but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should override both `textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:` and `drawTextInRect:` like this:

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds limitedToNumberOfLines:(NSInteger)numberOfLines
{
    return CGRectInset(bounds, MARGIN, MARGIN);
}

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawTextInRect: CGRectInset(self.bounds, MARGIN, MARGIN)];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked (more or less): I had to do some tweaking to the rect width to make things work properly with multiple lines, but I got it working in the end.

Comment: If you do this (in order to match a UITextView) you may also want to override sizeThatFits like this:
   - (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
   {
      CGSize fSize = [super sizeThatFits:size];
      fSize.width += 2* MARGIN;
      fSIze.height += 2 * MARGIN;
      return fSize;
    }

Comment: Doesn't work for me, it still doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation, it might be of some help. calls to super might not be returning the values you assume.

> You should not call this method
>   directly. This method should only be
>   overridden by subclasses that want to
>   change the receiver’s bounding
>   rectangle before performing any other
>   computations. Use the value in the
>   numberOfLines parameter to limit the
>   height of the returned rectangle to
>   the specified number of lines of text.
>   For this method to be called, there
>   must be a prior call to the sizeToFit
>   or sizeThatFits: method. Note that
>   labels in UITableViewCell objects are
>   sized based on the cell dimensions,
>   and not a requested size
>   The default implementation of this
>   method returns **the original** bounds
>   rectangle.

Good luck!

Comment: Actually, the documentation is incorrect with `limitedToNumberOfLines:0`. The passed in `bounds` has a `height` that looks like `INT_MAX_VALUE` or something, and the default implementation seems to reduce it to a rect high enough to fit the text.