# Alignment of text of the label in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to shift the text in the label slightly. I have already placed the text on the right by aligning in the attributes inspector. But I would like to move it slightly to the left. Not sure what button to press. I have looked through all the features in attributes inspector, but still not able to find it.

Here is how it looks like now: [image]

Like to move the zero slightly to the left somemore. How do i do it?

Comment: You can make the label a bit smaller, can't you? so it will not reach that far...

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3476646/550177

Comment: I will delete my answer cuz it my responsibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move the text within the label, you will have to subclass UILabel and override drawTextInRect: like this:

```
@implementation RDLabel

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width - 10, rect.size.height);
    [super drawTextInRect:newRect];
}
@end
```

This will move the text 10 points to the left if you have the text right justified.