# removing uinavigationbar title margins

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I modified my navigation bar as follows in app delegate:

```
 NSDictionary *settings = @{

                           UITextAttributeFont                 :  [UIFont fontWithName:@"impact" size:36.0],
                           UITextAttributeTextColor            :  [UIColor whiteColor],
                           UITextAttributeTextShadowColor      :  [UIColor clearColor],
                           UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset     :  [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetZero]};

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:settings];
```

But the font cuts down like this for the larger font. :

[image]

I tried doing this in viewWillAppear of my VC, :

```
 UIView *newTitleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
[newTitleView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:newTitleView];
```

Then I was going to align title to center. But that just doesn't seems right. Only thing I actually need is to remove margins at top and bottom of the title Label. How do I go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code and don't set setTitleTextAttributes

```
UILabel *titleView = (UILabel *)self.navigationItem.titleView;
    if (!titleView) {
        titleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        titleView.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
        titleView.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];

        titleView.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor]; // Change to desired color

       self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
        [titleView release];
    }
    titleView.text = title;
    [titleView sizeToFit];
```

Comment: initWithFrame: CGRectZero ??

Comment: It should work to give flexible width... If it's not working for you try.. [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(([self.title length] < 10 ? UITextAlignmentCenter : UITextAlignmentLeft), 0, 480,44)];
titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: `self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;` is somehow not working for me, I used `[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:titleView];`

Comment: yes. I didn't use your exact code. But thanks to point me in right direction. Is there a way to implement same thing in appDelegate so that I don't have to repeat it in each VC.

Comment: yes definitely... use a category for NavigationBar.. then you don't need to write code everywhere.. Just pass a titleStr in label..

Answer (score 2):

Well the easiest way i would suggest is to use a UIView with label and button customised for the requirement and use it,not on navigation bar.
mnavigation bar height customization is the trouble that the height is fixed and the subview also it may affect .So I suggest to go with a custom header view subclassed with UIView

Comment: Thats true, but there is only one thing left to be tweeked. Thats the vertical margins there, I was hoping I could just do it in nav Bar instead of changing whole nib layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass to the `UILabel` and override `drawTextInRect`: like this:

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIEdgeInsets insets = {0, 5, 0, 5};
    return [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)];
}
```

For more useful link you can find
 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476646/uilabel-text-margin)