# Make UILabel height so it fits the characters it contains exactly (with autolayout)

Tags: ios, autolayout, alignment, uilabel

I've seen that `UILabel` intrinsic size doesn't seem to fit exactly the characters it contains.

[image]

As you can see in the image, labels have some margin on top and bottom. I can make "Subtitle" get closer to "TITLE" using baseline (`title.baseline == subtitle.top`), but I would also want to align "TITLE" to its parent top.

I would like to use autolayout constraints if possible.

Comment: Fonts have lowercase descenders tat go below the baseline. The intrinsic size allows for that.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'd like a "current" intrinsic size with the characters that I'm using, not any possible character. Since I'm using caps there, I know I won't have lowercase descenders.

Comment: I posted a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34073666/1121497

Answer (score 1):

**Quick Fix**

If your font size is constant for labels, you can try subclassing `UILabel` and override `- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize`

```
-(CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    CGSize intrinsicSize = [super intrinsicContentSize];
    intrinsicSize.height -= 8; // Works good for system font size 17.0
    return intrinsicSize;
}
```

You might need to play with `intrinsicSize.height -= 8;` to get desired output.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about doing that. It's quite a hack, though... :p --- And I would like it to work for any font, size and characters. I would have to consider all of those and "cook" a magic number.