# UILabel extra spaces before and after text ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uilabel

Label shows text perfectly in portrait mode.
It also works properly when device rotates from portrait to landscape or landscape to portrait.

But when i open app in landscape mode it shows extra spaces before and after the text.

I have used `NumberOfLines = 0` and `sizeToFit`.
and also tried

```
CGSize aSize = [self.label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.label.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
self.label.frame = CGRectMake(self.label.frame.origin.x, self.label.frame.origin.y, self.label.frame.size.width, aSize.height);
```

You can check image here: 
http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2014-02-14_at_4.44.42_PM-7I55uWNF.png

Comment: I have used NumberOfLines = 0 and sizetofit. and also tried  
CGSize aSize = [self.label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.label.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
 self.label.frame = CGRectMake(self.label.frame.origin.x, self.label.frame.origin.y, self.label.frame.size.width, aSize.height);

Comment: I believe this question has been answered here already:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476646/uilabel-text-margin

Comment: post image of simulator..

Comment: I have not enough reputation to upload image.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code on your UIViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [myLabel sizeToFit];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    myLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = myLabel.frame.size.width;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use Autosizing from storyboard**
OR

```
self.label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

Comment: if u cannot post a screenshot here then upload it on dropbox and paste a link here. By looking at it may be i could be able to help you :)