# Is there a "space" character that is NOT trimmed from end of UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uilabel

I see LOTS of questions and answers about trimming the white space of of the end of a string.  My question is the opposite.

I intentionally DO WANT a blank space character at the end of my string and I do NOT want it to be automatically trimmed away when assigned to the `text` property of a `UILabel`.

I have tried adding all the unicode variations I could think of (NO-BREAK SPACE /u00a0; PUNCTUATION SPACE /u0008; TAG SPACE, etc) but they all get trimmed.

In my past life programming experience there was always available a "space" character what was not considered a "white space" specifically so it would be immune from auto-trimming.

Comment: What about adding it when the editing has completed...

Comment: As it is a UILabel and not a UITextField, I don't think it has the same "didEndEditing" methods available.

Comment: Right. Sorry about that but I was thinking about *UITextField*.

Comment: Anyway you can use KVO for that.

Comment: Still a noob here. What is KVO? Killer Voltron Organisms?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

Comment: In addition, a label cannot change the text without your code doing it. So, what's the point here?

Comment: My program IS setting the text. and iOS is trimming it.  Does KVO operate at an appropriate level/depth that it would allow me to "catch" the truncation that iOS is performing and prevent it from happening?

Comment: why do you need a blank space?

Comment: Simple really, I want my text right aligned but with a space at the right for visual clarity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476646/uilabel-text-margin

Answer (score 3):

I search for the answer for about a week, i've found that using the unicode "0009" (tab space) works for the UILabel

Comment: You can use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\t", @"your text"]` to append tab.

Answer (score 1):

Adding tab space didn't help me as I wanted just to add 1 space to the beginning and to the and of the label, so I came up with the solution which doesn't look nice, but is configurable & saved my life:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]}];

[string insertAttributedString:[self emptyAtributedWhitespace] atIndex:0];
[string appendAttributedString:[self emptyAtributedWhitespace]];

label.attributedText = string;
```

...

```
- (NSAttributedString *)emptyAtributedWhitespace
{
    // You can put any random string there or how many spaces you want
    return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"_" attributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor clearColor]}];
}
```