# Can I set ascender or descender for System UIFont?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uifont

I am creating a alert badge using UILabel using following code:

```
    [label setText:@"67"];
    UIFont * font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11];
    [label setFont:font];
    [label sizeToFit];

    [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    label.layer.cornerRadius = label.frame.size.height/2;
```

[image: Badge screenshot]

Everything is fine but vertical alignment of text is not correct. Its more close to top edge. How can I align text in vertical center of UILabel?

I read about ascender and descender properties of UIFont, can I use them to align text in vertical center of UILabel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an attributed string instead of a plain `NSString` for the label's text (so use the `attributedText` property instead of `text`), and use the `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` attribute [described here at Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to subclass `UILabel` in order to add margins to the label, so you could define a custom "top margin" to compensate the baseline shift.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476646/uilabel-text-margin) to view the implementation details.

Comment: It has more controls. Good to know this.

Answer (score -1):

To vertically align the text of UILabel use -

```
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[myLabel sizeToFit];
```

For detailed answer check [This SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel?rq=1)