# Remove UILabel padding

Tags: ios, iphone, uilabel, padding

If it were a TextView I could do

```
self.textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
```

But what I have is a multiline label. How do I remove the padding?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using iOS 8, try changing the insets value of `layoutMargins` property. If it doesn't work or you're targeting earlier versions, look at [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476646/uilabel-text-margin)

Answer (score 1):

`NSMutableParagraphStyle` has an attribute called lineSpacing. Try adding this attribute to an attributed string and setting the label's attributedText

Answer (score 1):

you can try this：

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str)
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 0.75 //or other values you like
attributedString.addAttribute(
    NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle,
    value: paragraphStyle,
    range: NSMakeRange(0, str.count)
)
typeLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
label.padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Answer (score -3):

I recommend to change your UILabel into UITextView and put this code.

```
yourTextView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);
```

don't forget to set yourTextView

```
yourTextView.editable = NO
yourTextView.scrollEnabled = NO
```