# Aligning UILabel and UIImage

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin.iOS and I want to have a UILabel and UIImage aligned with same margins to the container view. See image below

[image: Template]

Right now, the image and text has the same height but due to the padding of the label, the top and bottom have bigger margins. Btw, I already used SizeToFit().
Here's my code:

```
nfloat gap = 10f;
UIView containerView = new UIView ();
UILabel textView = new UILabel ();
textView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
textView.Text = "HELLO!";
textView.Font = UIFont.FromName ("Arial-BoldMT", 40f);
textView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.Bottom;
textView.SizeToFit ();
textView.Frame = new CGRect (gap, gap, textView.Frame.Width, textView.Frame.Height);
containerView.AddSubview (textView);

UIImageView imgView = new UIImageView (UIImage.FromBundle ("Sample-icon"));
imgView.Frame = new CGRect (textView.Frame.X + textView.Frame.Width + gap,
textView.Frame.Y, textView.Frame.Height, textView.Frame.Height);
imgView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;
containerView.AddSubview (imgView);

containerView.Frame = new CGRect(10, 50, gap + textView.Frame.Width + gap + imgView.Frame.Width + gap, gap + textView.Frame.Height + gap);
containerView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Yellow;
View.AddSubview (containerView);
```

Here how it looks like now:

[image: Current view]

My question is how can I remove all paddings (including top and bottom) and if still possible I can remove the small paddings of left and right

I can understand Objective-C codes so if there are references using it, kindly share

Thanks!

**UPDATE!**
Here's my CustomLabel with same result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5155382/3633534)

Set 0 for all in insets. So you won't get extra padding

**CustomLabel.h**

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface CustomLabel : UILabel

 @end
```

**CustomLabel.m**

```
#import "CustomLabel.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation CustomLabel

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

// for inset
-(void) drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIEdgeInsets insets = {0, 0, 0, 0};

    [super drawTextInRect: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)];    
}
```

**YourViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomLabel.h"

@interface YourViewController : UIViewController {
    CustomLabel *myLabel;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet CustomLabel *textView;

@end
```

Comment: Hi @Sujay, I tried that. I already tried subclassing a UILabel and it doesn't work.

Comment: @marsh08, have you used custom class name for your text field?

Comment: Do you mena somehting like this: textView = new CustomButtonLabel();.. ? Yes

Comment: you have used following code to create label
`UILabel textView = new UILabel();`
instead of using `UILabel` use your custom class name that you have created for subclassing the `UILabel`
try
`CustomLabel textView = new CustomLabel();`

Comment: sorry, the one above is not the one I'm really using but just the same implementation.

Comment: I updated my question to display the CustomLabel and as you can see, no effect. Thanks

Comment: didn't update the upper code. but it is updated in my code