# Xcode: How to add margin/padding to label text?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a label with text:

[image]

However, I want it have more padding (and for the edges to be a little rounded if possible). But when I stretch the label in my storyboard so that it appears to have padding, and then I restart the simulator, it doesn't add padding to it.

How would I do this? BTW, I'm using auto layout + objective c

Comment: I'm not sure that helps since I've never done that but maybe it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476646/uilabel-text-margin

Comment: is there a way to do it through storyboards?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to go the layout constraints route, this is probably the fitting solution for you:

You should use a container view and place the label inside of that. Then add constraints for the label, which will be equivalent to a padding.

[image]

Select the label and click the constraints panel at the bottom right in the Storyboard file.

[image: Label's constraints to container view]

With the label selected, apply layout constraints like seen above (make sure you select the red "lines" so that the constraints are actually applied).

[image: End result]

The orange view is the container view. The label is right inside of that.

Comment: I want to use only one view, label is container itself which contains text

Answer (score 6):

You can add round corners from storyboard select your UILabel (or any view) and go to inspector, on the identity inspector section add a value as shown in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to override UILabel's drawRect method

Sample code:

```
#import "OCPaddedLabel.h"
#define PAD 10.0f
#define PAD_VERT 6.0f

@implementation OCPaddedLabel

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIEdgeInsets insets = {PAD_VERT, PAD, PAD_VERT, PAD};
    [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)];
}
```

if you would like to add rounded corners, you need:

```
label.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0f;
label.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the padding on a label with a background color where text is aligned left or right, first select the label then in the attributes inspector at the top [and change text from Plain to Attributed in the dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQwRe.png)

Select the alignment of the text (in this example it aligns right) [click on the 3 dot menu button to the far right to open additional settings and change Text-Direction from Natural to Right To Left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbzRm.png)

Text in label should now have a bit of padding on the right side

Answer (score 1):

You can add margin with

```
yourLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)
```

Comment: One should edit constraints when using autolayout, not frames.