# How to center a SearchBar in the new navigationItem.searchController?

Tags: xcode, uinavigationitem, ios11, uisearchcontroller

This looks ugly.  I want to implement the new search controller for IOS 11 in the navigationItem.searchContoller space, however there is a large gap at the bottom.  How do I get rid of this ugly gap?

[image]

Comment: Maybe this can help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429397/xcode-how-to-add-margin-padding-to-label-text)

Comment: No this didn't help :(

Comment: Did you find a solution except for using titleView instead of searchController?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
searchController.searchBar.searchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: 8)
```

Comment: cancel button still not center :(