# UILabel borders expanded in regard to text

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I'm using Auto Layout to set `UILabel` constraints like follow:

```
[self.leadNewsLabel mas_remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.left.equalTo(self.containerForNewsText.mas_left).with.offset(16);
    make.top.equalTo(self.containerForNewsText.mas_top).with.offset(16);
    make.right.equalTo(self.containerForNewsText.mas_right).with.offset(-16);
    make.height.greaterThanOrEqualTo(@(50));
    make.bottom.equalTo(self.truncatedNewsText.mas_top).with.offset(-20); 
}];
```

I use Masonry lib to programmatically add constraints, syntax is pretty straightforward. However, for some reason UILabel expand its borders. Please take a look at screenshot from debugger:

[image]

You can easily see that label borders are not the same as text borders. How could i fix it?

Comment: did u try the text alignment to center ? and what is the offset in the constraints for ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri no i didnt. Offsets are obviously for layout frame relatively to other views.

Comment: if the tex alignment center didnt work, try to set the label margin....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476646/uilabel-text-margin

Comment: @TejaNandamuri thank you i will try.

Comment: Sadly its not work ;(