# Stackview with right aligned label needs padding

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout

I created the following layout:

[image]

The label on the right side, is included in a stackview, but is "clinging" to the right side of the screen when launching the app. I want to achieve some spacing, but don't know how to achieve it.

The expected output would look like this:
[image]

Comment: can you add your expected output. thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding another UIView as a spacer?

Comment: this link should help you. need to do subclassing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476646/uilabel-text-margin

Answer (score 2):

When `isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement` property is true, the stack view will layout its arranged views relative to its layout margins. So here,

```
stackView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 20)
stackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
```

The above will add 20 pixels width of padding to the right edge of the stackview. This can also be done via the storyboard.