# Add padding between label and its border

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have in my swift application some labels that should have border. I added border to my label but I want to have more spaces between the label and its border.

How can I do that?

Comment: Where do you want to add the space? Left padding, right padding?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476646/uilabel-text-margin ?

Comment: left, right, top and bottom

Comment: @Larme I already find this but when I added this to my code: `override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let insets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
        super.drawTextInRect(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
    }`  it gives me "Method does not override any method from its super class" and also "Value of type "UIViewController" has no member drawTextInRect"

Comment: It's a subclass of `UILabel` not of `UIViewController`.

Comment: So how it can be accepted inside my UIViewController?

Comment: wrap it in a view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
myLabel.frame.size.width = myLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width + 10
myLabel.frame.size.height = myLabel.intrinsicContentSize.height + 10
myLabel.textAlignment = .center
```

Comment: Glad to have helped you :)

Comment: it didn't work for me

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution would be to embed your label inside a view, and then add the border to this view, instead of to the label itself. I hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Add this class**

*PaddingLabel.swift*

```
import UIKit

class PaddingLabel: UILabel {

    var edgeInset: UIEdgeInsets = .zero

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let insets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: edgeInset.top, left: edgeInset.left, bottom: edgeInset.bottom, right: edgeInset.right)
        super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: insets))
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let size = super.intrinsicContentSize
        return CGSize(width: size.width + edgeInset.left + edgeInset.right, height: size.height + edgeInset.top + edgeInset.bottom)
    }
}
```

**2. change the class of your label to `PaddingLabel`**

[image]

**3. Add this code to your `ViewController`**

```
import UIKit

class LabelViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: PaddingLabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Setting the border
        label.layer.borderWidth = 1
        label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        
        //Setting the round (optional)
        label.layer.masksToBounds = true
        label.layer.cornerRadius = label.frame.height / 2
    
        //Setting the padding label
        label.edgeInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 10, bottom: 5, right: 10)
    
    }
}
```

#### Result

[image]
[image]

Comment: This was helpful, thank you! It's unfortunate the base UILabel doesn't come with this and you have to subclass!

Answer (score 0):

I did this (to get the text on the same place):

```
//label position
myLabel.layer.frame.size.width += 10
myLabel.layer.frame.origin.x -= 5
myLabel.textAlignment = .center

//border
myLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemTeal.cgColor
myLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
label.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
```