# Unable to add space between label and it's border

Tags: ios, swift, padding

I have a label with a rectangular border. I wish to add space between the label's text and the label's border.
I tried following the steps described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40385630/9735046

```
myLabel.frame.size.width = myLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width + 10
myLabel.frame.size.height = myLabel.intrinsicContentSize.height + 10
myLabel.textAlignment = .center
```

But it did not add space between my label's text and border.
How would I add space?

Comment: where you put this code ?

Comment: In my viewDidLoad() method

Comment: do you set the `text` property of you label before calculating size?

Comment: try it in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: @SergeyLevkachev  yes I have

Comment: @Sh_Khan viewDidLayoutSubviews did not work :(

Comment: @Karliene see answer ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `viewDidLoad` frame is not yet to be set so try this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    lb.text = "dbjsjdhsjhdshjdshjdshdjs"

    lb.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

    lb.layer.borderWidth = 3

    lb.textAlignment = .center

    view.addSubview(lb)

    lb.sizeToFit()

    lb.center = view.center
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    lb.frame.size.width = lb.intrinsicContentSize.width + 100

    lb.frame.size.height = lb.intrinsicContentSize.height + 100

    lb.center = view.center

}
```

//

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Auto-layout is probably overriding your size change. Try adding a size constraint to the label. Note that this is easier in a `Storyboard` than in code.

Comment: even if it's been setted with constraints this will override it . plus size constraint won't guarantee what text length in label will be

Comment: Until the next time something triggers a layout update, which might be immediately.

Comment: yes, but code is still in viewDidLayoutSubviews which will override it too

Comment: Yes if you put this code in viewDidLayoutSubviews then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

See its simple. If you have label width bigger than text and use textalignment as Center then it will work how you want and text will be in center having space at start & end of label. Like below :

[image]

If you don't want text-alignment as Center and want to keep text-alignment as left then same will look like below :

[image]

So now with left-aligned and you want space between border and text then you have to add white space before actual text value start like below:

```
    let strValue = "I want Space"
    label?.text = " \(strValue)"
```

And Result will be this :

[image]

So you can see the difference.