# UILabel rounding corners cuts-off text

Tags: ios, swift

I am using custom TableCell which has a label with **numberofLines = 0**

I wanted the label like this.

[image]

That is rounded only in three corners.For this to achieve i've written code like this in cell's swift file.I've extended the UIView basically.

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

And i've used this like this to round my corners.

```
self.chatLabel.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft,.bottomLeft,.bottomRight], radius: 7.0)
```

**But the problem is when label's content is bigger than the cell's row height it's not showing the content**

Please just see the second cell's label in **first picture** .It's content is not showing.
But when i remove the rounded corner's code everything is working fine but lost my corner radius.

[image]

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.Thanks.

**Edited:**

My cell is like this.

[image]

And i am achieving chat UI using the code below.

```
var cellTypeToDraw:cellType {
        get {
            return self.cellTypeToDraw
        }
        set(newValue) {
            switch newValue {
            case .cellTypeReceiver:
                self.leftImage.isHidden = true
                 self.rightImage.isHidden = false
                self.chatLabel.textAlignment = .right
                self.chatLabel.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft,.bottomLeft,.bottomRight], radius: 7.0)
            case .cellTypeSender:
                self.rightImage.isHidden = true
                self.leftImage.isHidden = false
                self.chatLabel.textAlignment = .left
                self.chatLabel.roundCorners(corners: [.topRight,.bottomLeft,.bottomRight], radius: 7.0)
            }
            self.leftImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.leftImage.bounds.size.width/2
            self.rightImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.rightImage.bounds.size.width/2
           // self.chatLabel.sizeToFit()
           // self.chatLabel.autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight
        }
    }
```

and accessing this variable in cellForRowAtIndexPath like this.

```
 if indexPath.row % 2 != 0 {
            cell.cellTypeToDraw = .cellTypeReceiver
        }
        else {
            cell.cellTypeToDraw = .cellTypeSender
        }
```

Comment: I understand there is a `UITableViewCell`, if so, then have you implemented the necessary constraints for it to grow according to the text inside?

Comment: yes. i already mentioned it's tableCell.

Comment: you need to add margins to the UILabel [checkout this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476646/uilabel-text-margin)

Comment: If it helps, you can take at the rounded corners method in this lib: https://github.com/appsquickly/NanoFrame  . . it is old ObjC code.

Comment: Try adding Text before masking for corner  radios .

Comment: already tried.:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You're doing it too early.

You set the `cellTypeToDraw` and thus call your `roundCorners(corners:, radius:)` method at a point in time when the layout isn't done yet. In `cellForRow(at:)` you get a *recycled* cell whose `chatLabel` still has the frame that matched the text it displayed previously.

A quick fix would be to move this corner-rounding to the cell's `layoutSubviews()` method. Something like:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    chatLabel.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft,.bottomLeft,.bottomRight], radius: 7.0)
}
```

(You can check the `cellTypeToDraw` there as well if you only want to have rounded corners for *some* cell types.)

---

By the way:

#### Tip 1:

**You should never do something like that:**

```
var cellTypeToDraw:cellType {
    get {
        return self.cellTypeToDraw
    }
    // ...
}
```

This will result in an **endless recursion** when you ever try to call `cellTypeToDraw` and eventually crash your app. By implementing the getter and the setter you define a *computed* property that is *not* backed by an instance variable. `self.cellTypeToDraw` doesn't *have* a value. It simply calls the getter again which returns `self.cellTypeToDraw` again and so on.

Solution: Don't use a computed property but a "regular" one which *is* backed by an instance variable and do all your cell setup in the property's observer:

```
var cellTypeToDraw:cellType {
    didSet {
        // configure your cell here
    }
}
```

#### Tip 2:

You can (and should) omit all the `self.` prefixes in Swift for better readability and less work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It's working perfectly. However didSet is not working. willSet is working here.

Comment: `didSet` will also work if you use the property's name instead of `newValue`.

Answer (score -2):

Add a view insert your label and add some space between your label and that view.

Comment: i don't understand. My label has 8 pixel constant with the image.

Comment: answer edited. no problem with image to label distance. problem is with u need some padding in label. and add roundCorners to view.