# how to programmatically make label larger?

Tags: swift, uilabel

Right now, the edges of the label line up exactly with the end of the text - I want to give the text some padding(?) or space so that you still see some of the background. Is this a constraints issue?

```
let lblTitle: UILabel = {
    let lbl=UILabel()
    lbl.text="Try this quiz."
    lbl.textColor=UIColor.black
    lbl.textAlignment = .justified
    lbl.font = UIFont(name: "Gotham", size: 50)
    lbl.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.8)
    lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    lbl.layer.masksToBounds = true
    lbl.numberOfLines=0
    lbl.sizeToFit()
    lbl.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    lbl.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
    return lbl
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UILabel text margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476646/uilabel-text-margin)

Comment: I'll use constraints for this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should just use constraints (ie put the label in a container and give it space to to container equal to the padding you want, and only give the container 2 position constraints so it infers height and width from the label + padding), but if not its easy enough to do by adding a negative inset to the frame right after you call `lbl.sizeToFit`.  For instance this adds 10 padding points in every direction:

```
lbl.frame.insetBy(dx: -20, dy: -20)
```